# Elasticsearch query failure

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I've built a small search app using Elasticsearch and AngularJS. I've nearly implemented an autocomplete feature using AngularJS UI Bootstrap Typeahead. For some reason the ES query for the search function is failing... **IF** I select terms from the autocomplete dropdown. When I simply enter a search term and click search, it works fine.

I'm using an ES `match_phrase_prefix` query for autocomplete and a `multi-match` query for the actual search

The HTML looks like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchTerms" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="{{ searchTerms }}" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" uib-typeahead="query as query._source.ymme for query in getSuggestions($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="search($item)">
```

The `typeahead-on-select="search($item)"` performs search on selection, so why can't it parse `multi-match` query for search if the `match_phrase_prefix` query is working fine for autocomplete?

**UPDATE** Complete error message

```
    All shards failed for phase: [query_fetch]
org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [hugetestindex][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"multi_match":{"query":{"fields":["content","title"],"query":{"_index":"hugetestindex","_type":"doc","_id":"22","_score":2.760369,"_source":{"ymme":"bourne supremacy"}},"operator":"and"}}},"size":100,"from":0,"highlight":{"fields":{"title":{"number_of_fragments":0},"content":{"number_of_fragments":10,"fragment_size":300}}}}]]
```

searchTerms is the user's search query, ng-model on the input element.

**UPDATE 2** I changed `typeahead-on-select="search($item)"` TO `typeahead-on-select="search.searchTerms($item)"` and that seems to have taken care of the 400 Bad Request error I was getting in the console tab, however, the query is still failing... and it looks like its not attempting to search on selection now...?

This is the query from searchService

```
index: 'hugetestindex',
  body: {
    "query": {
      "multi_match": {
        "query": searchTerms,
        "fields": ["content", "title"],
        "operator": "and"
        }
      },
    size: 100,
    from: 0,
    highlight: {
      fields: {
        "title": {number_of_fragments: 0},
        "content": {number_of_fragments: 10,fragment_size: 300}
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: past the complete error please. 
what is searchTerms ?

Comment: @AlainIb please look at UPDATE above for the info you requested, thanks